# Возможно ли вызов функции mql4 из dll?

Tags: c++, mql

Сейчас приходиться, все вычисления делать в dll. И возвращать результат на основе которого принимается решение: открывать позицию, закрывать и т.д. А само открытие позиции делается в mql4.

Вопрос, возможно ли как то импортировать функции в dll. Чтобы прямо в dll вызывать открытие позиции?

файл bot.mq4

```
#import "bot.dll"
   double test();
#import

int start()
{
 test();
}
```

файл bot.dll

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <atlstr.h>

#define MT4_EXPFUNC __declspec(dllexport)


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return(TRUE);
}

void test()
{
    // отсюда, я могу открыть позицию?
}
```

Comment: Вот примерчик бы действительно не помешал (хотя бы псевдокодом), т.к. непонятно что Вам надо. Вызвать из одной функции другую?

Comment: Подробнее расписал, надеюсь немного понятнее стало :)

Comment: Что такое "открыть позицию"? Вызвать функцию, которая слинкована вместе с `start()`, которая вызывает `test()` в dll?  Можно, например, если передать ее адрес в `test()`.

Comment: > Что такое "открыть позицию"? Имелось ввиду вызвать функцию OrderSend из MT4.

Answer (score 0):

В терминале МТ4 нельзя вызвать встроенные MQL функции из dll

Answer (score 0):

можно послать "указание" на открытие позиции... и отловить его в самом MT, прокручивая функцию из DLL в бесконечном цикле for(;;) или while(true) - соответственно, условие выхода из цикла проверять в самом цикле или выходить при закрытии EA... у такого подхода ("приказ" из dll) возможен один минус - скорость (нужно время для возврата переменной из dll)